# What are the effects of rotating of professionals among different projects during software development?

Tags: agile, team-management

Currently, I am performing a research focused on the effects of rotation in software development.

So, I'm interested in understand how developers, software engineers, testers, that is, all individuals participating in the software development process, see and feel about this practice of rotation among projects or teams, that many companies apply.

So I was wondering, if someone around here has experienced this in his/her job. Like, you are in the middle of a project and the manager rotated you to another project. You had to leave your team, your tasks were assigned to another person and you start to work in a different project with a different team.

I'd like to know how does it feel, like,

- how was this experience?
- How did it happen?
- What were the positive aspects (good things that the rotation brought)?
- What were the negative aspects (bad things that the rotation brought)?
- How did it affect your performance at work?
- How did it affect your previous team?
- How do you see or what do you think about this process of rotation among different projects in the middle of the development?

I am very thankful in advance for all the answers.

Comment: Vote to CLOSE - Its not related to SQA, I guess. You need to try on some different channels Ronnie. And another things is Stack family has few rules where they promote to avoid opinion based questions!

Comment: I agree that this question is not a perfect match for Stack, but the **fact is being asked here** shows that Stack forums are considered valuable resource to the community and source of expertise. There is no other forum (AFAIK) which can be better fit. It is certainly more valuable that the almost daily questions like "I have no clue about programming, how I can become automated tester?" or "XPATH does not work for me, what else is new?"

Comment: So I suggest to keep it open. It might even give a clue to the people interested in QA career - assuming they are bright enough to search forum. And if they cannot search, nothing will help them anyway, so... I vote to keep it.

Comment: If policy nazis will insist on closing it, folks at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be more open-minded to consider and answer it.

Answer (score 1):

**How was this experience?**

- It was a very positive experience for me and I personally liked it.
- I met lots of dev and testers from other departments and got to learn lots of more.

**How did it happen?**

- The company I was working for was losing lots of money and had to cut its budget. Instead of having everyone assigned to a certain project or team, we were reformed into various tribes, that is a group of dev, business analysts and testers working on a release; after the release, we would be re-assigned into other tribes working on something different.

**What were the positive aspects (good things that the rotation brought)?**

- Met lots of new people
- Learned more
- More productive than before
- Everyone was more active overall
- Everyone was happier than before
- The Myth is: some people say rotating people around reduce proficiency, but it actually increases it from what I have seen. The reason might have been people were more engaged and more willing to commit.

**What were the negative aspects (bad things that the rotation brought)?**

- You hardly got time to know someone well
- There was once I asked someone to help me, she made a promise and forgot about it; my work was seriously delayed by this. Having little personal connection between us might have contributed to this.

**How did it affect your performance at work?**

- Overall positively

**How did it affect your previous team?**

- Previous team was no longer in existence, so it does not apply.

**How do you see or what do you think about this process of rotation among different projects in the middle of the development?**

- My personal opinion is **FOR** it.
- Having someone stays in a role all the time does not increase proficiency, instead this person may get bored.
- Rotating people around eliminate idle employees, people have to be on the move constantly. I prefer a fast-paced working environment than a slow one.

I have turned into a contractor since I left my previous employers, now I rotate among different customers; I continue to meet different people and get to learn different testing tools and environments they use. Moreover, it is inevitable to play multi-role in an Agile cross-functional team.